# C++ Class Design/ Excluding Base Class members

Tags: c++, c++20

Assuming I just created a class named Base with 2 or 3 Members, that's about this:

```
class Base
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string  number;
public:
    virtual std::string  get() const;
    virtual void set();
//...
};
```

And in the next step I want to create a few derived classes form this class. But in some of the derived classes I don't need all members of the Base class.

How can I exclude some members of Base-class in a derived class and keep the others?

For Instance in:

```
class Derived_One : public Base {
private:
    std::string wight;
    int A;
public:
    //...
};
```

I want to keep only the first attribute of the Base Class (`std::string name`) and remove the second attribute which is `std::string number`. How can I exclude it in the derived class `Drive_One`?

I am looking for an elegant solution for this change or a widely known Design Pattern which I do not know yet.

Comment: Don't you need the `name` member at all, or do you want your own _override_? Or just prevent public access through the `get()`?

Comment: You can't. Suppose you pass a `Drived_one` object to a function `foo()` accepting a `Base` argument, `foo()` can access the `number` member of the `Base` object. If you remove a member of a derived class, you sabotage the C++ base/derived polymorphism.

Comment: if a derived class does not need what the base class has then it should not derive from it. This is a sign of your base class doing at least two orthononal things which is already way too much for a single class

Comment: but what is the solution? Just writing several standalone classes although the code in some of them is particulary the same?

Comment: there is too little context. solution to what? In the case of `Base` and `Derived_One` not wanting to inherit from `Base` the solution is to not inherit from `Base` ;). Inheritance is not the solution for everything. Picking only some members to inherit is just not possible

Comment: " Inheritance is not the solution for everything".  Ok. I agree ;)

Comment: @Amir: "*but what is the solution?*" This problem is not a circumstance you should encounter. That is, the idea that you would want to inherit from something without getting all of its members is essentially contradictory.

Comment: @max66 will you copy this into the answer?

Comment: you made it private, so already it's hidden from the derived class. that's all you can or should do.

Comment: It’s totally legitimate to use inheritance as a means of sharing implementations with or without interfaces, especially in C++ with multiple and private inheritance available.  (Sometimes it’s just to control initialization order.)  That said, you have to expect the result to involve several small classes that don’t correspond well to any application domain object, since it’s still the case that you can add but never subtract.

Answer (score 1):

If your derived class only needs some of the base class, it is a sign that the base class should be split into two. Either one class derived from the other or two separate classes.

An example of the first case could be something like this:

```
class Base_One
{
private:
    std::string name;
public:
//...
};

class Base_Two : public Base_One
{
private:
    std::string number;
public:
//...
};

class Derived_One : public Base_One
{
private:
    std::string wight;
    int A;
public:
    //...
};

class Derived_Two : public Base_Two
...
```

In the second case (if it does not make sense for `Base_Two` to derive from `Base_One`), `Base_One` and `Base_Two` would be separate classes and derived classes would derive from one or both of them, i.e. the example above would be modified as follows:

```
class Base_Two
{
private:
    std::string number;
public:
//...
};

...

class Derived_Two : public Base_One, public Base_Two
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> derived classes I don't need all members of the Base class.

Which simply says: This is not a common base class!

Whats to do:

Option 1)
Split base class to several ones and create a linear hierarchy structure.

But this may come to a point, where your design would be to complex, especially if it feels natural to cross call from different members of different classes in the hierarchy.

Option 2)
If your design becomes more complex by simply splitting to linear hierarchy, you should give [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) a chance.

This enables to inject special functionality into a class hierarchy and keeps the design cleaner. The bad side is, that this may lead to a lot of template instances which waste memory. You have a more maintainable design but you may pay with higher memory consumption.

What is the best for your design can't be answered on the fly from some lines of code. Simply try to understand both options and take a decision. Maybe you will change it later.